# How to enabled gdb -g3 debug level with CMake?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, cmake, gdb

When you would like to enable debug on CMake, you use `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, but this only sets `-g` which is the default debug level.

> -glevel
> Request debugging information and also use level to specify how much information. The default level is 2.
>
> Level 0 produces no debug information at all. Thus, -g0 negates -g.
>
> Level 1 produces minimal information, enough for making backtraces in parts
> of the program that you don't plan to debug. This includes descriptions
> of functions and external variables, but no information about local
> variables and no line numbers.
>
> Level 3 includes extra information, such as all the macro definitions present
> in the program. Some debuggers support macro expansion when you use
> -g3.

How to make the `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` set `-g3` instead of `-g`?

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/864902/4934640
2. https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Og -g3 ...`

Comment: Can you show an example? i.e., `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Og -g3"`?

Comment: I set it in the cmake file `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Og -g3 ...`  Usually when I set g3 I optimize -Og (not supported by all targets but for sure by arm-none-eabi)

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`, so it only a affects the code when CMake is building in Debug mode:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g3 -ggdb")
```

References:

1. [Change default value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and friends in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209/change-default-value-of-cmake-cxx-flags-debug-and-friends-in-cmake)
2. [CMake - compile with /MT instead of /MD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800166/cmake-compile-with-mt-instead-of-md)